# How to transform a cumulative time series to a non-cumulative one in R?

Tags: r

I am given a dataset of a blogger who kept track of how many views her video got since day it was released. The problem says that the cumulative number of views is included in the data set. For example: day 2 (August 26, 2019) has 111 views meaning 111 views in 2 days. I am asked to create a time series plot of the DAILY views, not cumulative. And I am just lost here..Does it just mean plot.ts(data$views)? Should I just specify the column I will be using by specifying it through the dollar sign? Or should I use lag1 difference so it would just kind of take the difference btw each day and apparently provide me daily views?

[image: dataset]

Reproducible data:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1566687600, 1566774000, 1566860400, 
1566946800, 1567033200, 1567119600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), views = c(49L, 111L, 167L, 218L, 270L, 312L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would really help the community to help you if you made your question reproducible [reprex]. Include a minimal data set - you can use `dput(head(dataset))` - and code which demonstrates what you have tried. May be also an indication of what  output you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `diff`:

```r
df$daily_views <- diff(c(0, df$views))
df
        date views daily_views
1 2019-08-25    49          49
2 2019-08-26   111          62
3 2019-08-27   167          56
4 2019-08-28   218          51
5 2019-08-29   270          52
6 2019-08-30   312          42
```

Comment: That is what I did and it made the most sense! The dateset has actually 250 observations and eventually it is asking to predict the CUMULATIVE views up to a certain date using the model we fitted using DAILY views..and I cant recall covering this in class. How would I do that? thank you

Comment: @Villy if you have your predicted daily views in a variable called `predicted` then you just do `cumsum(predicted)`

Comment: So I have predicted daily views on day 252 by using the fitted model, so I did it manually by finding the views on day 251 and plugged that in. Using predict(mod1, n.ahead =2) I verified that my value for day 252 is correct. Now to find cumulative views on day 252, would cumsum() work? What if I need to do it manually by using the fitted model fro daily views? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the ideal situation would be to use lag() to make a new column as I do below:

```
library(dplyr)


#dummy data

df<- data.frame(c("day1", "day2", "day3"), c(50, 150, 350))
colnames(df) <- c("day", "views")

#The function
df <-df %>% 
  mutate(per_day_view = ifelse(views == 50, views, views -lag(views)))

#Generic plot, but the x axis would be actual dates
plot(df$day, df$per_day_view)
```

I apologize for the ifelse() function, not sure how to make the first row maintain its values.